# How add legend to a bar-chart based on data in an object dynamically (d3)

Tags: d3.js, bar-chart

I am really new to the realm of D3 and based on the book of 'Interactive Data visualization for the web', I managed to create a Bar chart which is mostly based on the code from the following [link.](https://github.com/alignedleft/d3-book/blob/master/chapter_06/21_making_a_bar_chart_aligned.html)

The problem is I don't manage to add a legend to my bar chart based on an object dynamically.

I have tried consulting youtube videos and other stackoverflow questions related to 'adding a legend to a bar-chart', however in my opinion I couldn't find the question concerning how one is able to retrieve keys from an array of objects and use the data to add as an legend to the bar-chart. 
For now all my bars also have the same color, see the second code below.

See the code below for the formatting of my object which is embedded in an array.
The name 'key' and 'value' are fixed, while the amount of the objects and their corresponding name and value differ after an click event of the user ( which determines which variables will be included in the object).

The following [example](http://jsfiddle.net/juY5E/7/) is able create a legend, however in this case the formatting of the object is somehow different than in my case and my current knowledge of D3 is limitd, so I have no idea in which ways I have to adapt the code.

```
2: {key: "bedrijfsvestigingen_Sbi2008_BedrijfsvestigingenTotaal", value: 490}
3: {key: "bedrijfsvestigingen_Sbi2008_BedrijfsvestigingenNaarActiviteit_M_nZakelijkeDienstverlening", value: 165}
4: {key: "bedrijfsvestigingen_Sbi2008_BedrijfsvestigingenNaarActiviteit_R_uCultuur_Recreatie_OverigeDiensten", value: 120}
5: {key: "bedrijfsvestigingen_Sbi2008_BedrijfsvestigingenNaarActiviteit_K_lFinancieleDiensten_OnroerendGoed", value: 15}
6: {key: "bedrijfsvestigingen_Sbi2008_BedrijfsvestigingenNaarActiviteit_ALandbouw_BosbouwEnVisserij", value: 0}
7: {key: "bedrijfsvestigingen_Sbi2008_BedrijfsvestigingenNaarActiviteit_H_p_JVervoer_InformatieEnCommunicatie", value: 85}];
```

Based on the code from the book and accounting for other variables, I have currently the following code for visualizing a bar chart, in which the values (see object above) are shown in the bar charts and the color of the bar are all blueish. However there is not yet an legend included in my current code. Therefore I am wondering how one is able to dynamically create a legend based on the 'keys' ( in my case)in the object and represent the corresponding color bound to the bars. I would like to achieve the lowest image which I have drawn a sketch of.[image: This is a rough idea of what I would like to achieve with d3]

```
                var svg = d3.select("#barchart")
                    .select("svg")
                    .remove("svg");

                //Width and height
                var w = 600;
                var h = 250;
                var padding=20;



                var xScale = d3.scaleBand()
                    .domain(d3.range(dataset.length))
                    .rangeRound([w - padding,padding ])
                    .paddingInner(0.05);

                var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
                    .domain([0, d3.max(dataset, function (d) {
                        return d.value;
                    })])
                    .range([padding,h - padding]);
                    console.log("yscale",yScale);

                //Define key function, to be used when binding data
                var key = function (d) {
                    console.log("key", d);
                    return d.key;
                };


                // d3.select("svg").remove();
                //Create SVG element
                var svg = d3.select("#barchart")
                    .append("svg")
                    .attr("width", w)
                    .attr("height", h);
                console.log("svg", svg);

                //Create bars
                svg.selectAll("rect")
                    .data(dataset, key)     //Bind data with custom key function
                    .enter()
                    .append("rect")
                    .attr("x", function (d, i) {
                        return xScale(i);
                    })
                    .attr("y", function (d) {
                        return h - yScale(d.value);
                    })
                    .attr("width", xScale.bandwidth())
                    .attr("height", function (d) {
                        return yScale(d.value);
                    })
                    // .attr("data-legend", function (d) { return d.key })
                    .attr("fill", function (d) {
                        return "rgb(0, 0, " + (d.value * 10) + ")";
                    });
                //Create labels
                svg.selectAll("text")
                    .data(dataset, key)     //Bind data with custom key function
                    .enter()
                    .append("text")
                    .text(function (d) {
                        return d.value;
                    })
                    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
                    .attr("x", function (d, i) {
                        return xScale(i) + xScale.bandwidth() / 2;
                    })
                    .attr("y", function (d) {
                        return h - yScale(d.value) + 14;
                    })
                    .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
                    .attr("font-size", "11px")
                    .attr("fill", "white");
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of what is the result you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @torresomar, I have included a rough idea of what I would like to achieve in the first post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood correctly this is what you should need.
[Plunker with working code](https://plnkr.co/edit/byZ3wQFua3mud8bdcYmh?p=preview).

First of all I would encourage to use an margin object which will allow better flexibility when dealing with charts

```
var margin = {
  top: 20,
  right: 20,
  bottom: 20,
  left: 20
};
```

We want to display the data with an [odinal scale](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale#ordinal-scales) from the data and example you provided.

```
{key: "bedrijfsvestigingen_Sbi2008_BedrijfsvestigingenTotaal", value: 490}
{key: "bedrijfsvestigingen_Sbi2008_BedrijfsvestigingenNaarActiviteit_M_nZakelijkeDienstverlening", value: 165}
{key: "bedrijfsvestigingen_Sbi2008_BedrijfsvestigingenNaarActiviteit_R_uCultuur_Recreatie_OverigeDiensten", value: 120}
{key: "bedrijfsvestigingen_Sbi2008_BedrijfsvestigingenNaarActiviteit_K_lFinancieleDiensten_OnroerendGoed", value: 15}
{key: "bedrijfsvestigingen_Sbi2008_BedrijfsvestigingenNaarActiviteit_ALandbouw_BosbouwEnVisserij", value: 0}
{key: "bedrijfsvestigingen_Sbi2008_BedrijfsvestigingenNaarActiviteit_H_p_JVervoer_InformatieEnCommunicatie", value: 85}];
```

Taking into account that probably the first element is a sum of sorts of the dataset I think it shouldn't be included in the chart since it is an aggregation of the elements we want to display.
(In case you need to display it as an element you should be able to do it quickly after reviewing the answer)

The element structure in your dataset is the following:

```
{
  key: "bedrijfsvestigingen_Sbi2008_BedrijfsvestigingenNaarActiviteit_H_p_JVervoer_InformatieEnCommunicatie", 
  value: 85
}
```

The domain of our `xScale` should be all the key values in our dataset, since the key is a huge string, I created a custom property in each element called label

```
{
  key:
    "bedrijfsvestigingen_Sbi2008_BedrijfsvestigingenNaarActiviteit_M_nZakelijkeDienstverlening",
  label: "Business Services",
  value: 165
}
```

Lets create our scale with the correct domain and range:

```
var xScale = d3
  .scaleBand()
  .domain(dataset.map(d => d.label)) // All our label properties
  .rangeRound([0, w - margin.left - margin.right]) // This scale will map our values from [0, width - margin.left - margin.right]
  .paddingInner(0.05);
```

The yScale was almost correct, we just need to change it a little to use our margin object and use the correct range
The range must start from 0, if we used padding as the starting point our values will have an offset, since our values would be mapped from [padding, h - padding]. If we wanted to display a zero the value would be mapped to the padding value, if this is way you want to show the information keep it that way. In this case we will modify the scale.

```
var yScale = d3
  .scaleLinear()
  .domain([
    0,
    d3.max(dataset, function(d) {
      return d.value;
    })
  ])
  .range([0, h - margin.top - margin.bottom]);
```

Next we will create a function to get the desired value from our elements

```
var xKey = function(d) {
  return d.label;
};
```

Add our svg with some visual cues to help visualizing the way the elements are layed out:

```
var svg = d3
  .select("#barchart")
  .append("svg")
  .style("background", "rgb(243, 243, 243)")
  .style("border", "1px dashed #b4b4b4")
  .attr("width", w)
  .attr("height", h);
```

We want to use a margin, so lets use a group tag to achieve this, we could individually set the margin in each group/element we desired but I find this way simpler and clearer

```
var g = svg
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", `translate(${margin.left}, ${margin.top})`);
```

We will need the width and height of the chart with the margins taken into account, lets define them really quick:

```
const customWidth = w - margin.left - margin.right;
const customHeight = h - margin.top - margin.bottom;
```

Let us add a rect to show where will our rects will be displayed:

```
g.append("rect")
  .attr("fill", "#e3e3e3")
  .attr("width", customWidth)
  .attr("height", customHeight);
```

Lets deal with the rect creation, in your code you had a custom fill function which modified the b value within the RGB color values. In this case since we are dealing with categorical data we will use an array of colors for the rects.

```
g.append("g")
  .attr("class", "rect__container")
  .selectAll("rect")
  .data(dataset, xKey) //Bind data with custom key function
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("x", function(d, i) {
    return xScale(xKey(d)); // use our key function
  })
  .attr("y", function(d) {
    return customHeight - yScale(d.value); // use our custom size values
  })
  .attr("width", xScale.bandwidth())
  .attr("height", function(d) {
    return yScale(d.value);
  })
  .attr("fill", function(d, i) {
    return d3.schemeCategory10[i]; // use an array of colors and use the index to decide which color to use
  });
```

We have two options to show the labels of the chart:

We can create an x-axis or the desired legends. We will do both since it won't affect the outcome of the chart and either one of them can be removed.

```
var margin = {
  top: 20,
  right: 300, // modifiy our margin to have space to display the legends
  bottom: 50,
  left: 20
};

var legendElement = g
  .append("g")
  .attr("class", "legend__container")
  .attr("transform", `translate(${customWidth}, ${margin.top})`) // set our group position to the end of the chart
  .selectAll("g.legend__element")
  .data(xScale.domain()) // use the scale domain as data
  .enter()
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
    return `translate(${10}, ${i * 30})`; // provide an offset for each element found in the domain
  });

legendElement
  .append("text")
  .attr("x", 30)
  .attr("font-size", "14px")
  .text(d => d);

legendElement
  .append("rect")
  .attr("x", 0)
  .attr("y", -15)
  .attr("width", 20)
  .attr("height", 20)
  .attr("fill", function(d, i) {
    return d3.schemeCategory10[i]; // use the same category color that we previously used in rects
  });
```

Now lets use the axis approach:

```
// create axis
var x_axis = d3.axisBottom().scale(xScale);
//Append group and insert axis
g.append("g")
  .attr("transform", `translate(${0}, ${customHeight})`)
  .call(x_axis);
g.append("g")
  .attr("transform", `translate(${customWidth / 2}, ${customHeight + 40})`)
  .append("text")
  .text("Activities")
  .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
  .attr("font-size", "14px")
  .attr("font-weight", "bold")
  .style("text-transform", "uppercase")
  .attr("text-anchor", "middle");
```

And finally create the labels for the value in our data:

```
//Create labels
g.append("g")
  .attr("class", "text__container")
  .selectAll("text")
  .data(dataset, xKey) //Bind data with custom key function
  .enter()
  .append("text")
  .text(function(d) {
    return d.value;
  })
  .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
  .attr("x", function(d, i) {
    return xScale(xKey(d)) + xScale.bandwidth() / 2;
  })
  .attr("y", function(d) {
    return customHeight - yScale(d.value) + 14;
  })
  .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
  .attr("font-size", "11px")
  .attr("fill", "white");
```

Comment: thank you for the elaborated explanation. To be honest I don't completely quite understand the code, but it works :). I guess I will need more experience in order to understand how d3 works. Nevertheless, thank you very much. I had another question, I found the bar-chart a little bit on the big side. So I was wondering how I should change the width, height, margin, padding in such a way that I will get the halve of what I currently have.

Comment: If you want to make the chart as a whole smaller you could just change the width and height values in the plunker code, in case you may just want to make the bar width smaller you may use `paddingInner(number)`, for example try `.paddingInner(0.5)` in the plunker code and see if that is what you are aiming for